# What is the correct magento CE 1.9 paypal success url?

Tags: magento, paypal

We have magento CE 1.9 which we are trying to get some analytics on and I have seen many posts on the internet about setting up paypal with magento. I believe we have everything setup correctly for paypal standard checkout except for the return URL.

Some of the sources I found on the internet say to use 
http://www.storename.com/checkout/onepage/success/

Where others say to use 
http://www.storename.com/paypal/standard/success/

which one is actually correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An order finally reached analytics via:
http://www.storename.com/paypal/standard/success/

Other orders were completed but did not reach alalytics, I can only speculate on the reason for this. One possible cause I have read about, is premature closing of the browser window. This could prevent our sites success page from loading the analytics javascript.